# Splitting youtube video url

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube

I need to get the id from a youtube video url. I am using split method But in console it gives following error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

My video url is:
`https://www.youtube.com/embed/juIJGBxj-4w`

### And my code is

```
id = url.split('/')[1].split('embed')[1];
```

Comment: `id = url.split("/").filter(Boolean)[3]` will give you the id

Answer (score 3):

> The regular expression will extract the video ID from any YouTube URL
>   and it works with shortened URLs (youtu.be) and embed URLs
>   (youtube.com/embed/) as well.

```
 function extractVideoID(url){
        var regExp = /^.*((youtu.be\/)|(v\/)|(\/u\/\w\/)|(embed\/)|(watch\?))\??v?=?([^#\&\?]*).*/;
        var match = url.match(regExp);
        if ( match && match[7].length == 11 ){
            return match[7];
        }else{
            alert("Could not extract video ID.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks bro. But im also working with vimeo.Can you please give me for both .You can see here what i want : http://jsfiddle.net/235xuwjn/

Answer (score 0):

forExample youtube url is 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abcdefghij'

and i will split it with following code

```
id = url.split('?')[1].split('=')[1];
```

Comment: how can i differentiate this two url structure? `https://www.youtube.com/embed/juIJGBxj-4w` and `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abcdefghij`

Comment: @SumaiyaSalam in reality url will be one i gave above.and u can see that there is '?' and '=' in youtube url.

Answer (score 0):

```
url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/juIJGBxj-4w"
id = url.split('/');
var indexOfEmbed = id.indexOf("juIJGBxj-4w");
id[indexOfEmbed]
```

**Output:**

---

"juIJGBxj-4w"

**And this Solution is for all url using regex:**

---

```
var regExp = /^.*(youtu.be\/|v\/|u\/\w\/|embed\/|watch\?v=|\&v=)([^#\&\?]*).*/;
var match = url.match(regExp);
if (match && match[2].length == 11) {
  return match[2]; // use console.log if your run code in browser console 
} else {
  //error
}
```

**And this Solution is for all url without regex:**

**For this type of url**

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8nQa1cJyX8&a=GxdCwVVULXctT2lYDEPllDR0LRTutYfW

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8nQa1cJyX8
```

---

```
 var url ="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u8nQa1cJyX8&a=GxdCwVVULXctT2lYDEPllDR0LRTutYfW"

 var video_id = window.location.search.split('v=')[1];// use url insted of window.location.search

Or 

 var video_id = url.split('v=')[1];
    var ampersandPosition = video_id.indexOf('&');
    if(ampersandPosition != -1) {
      video_id = video_id.substring(0, ampersandPosition);
    }
```

Comment: Why `id.indexOf("juIJGBxj-4w")` this? it would not be same? if i understood correctly

Answer (score 0):

The problem is more complex than it seems, because all Youtube URL do not begin gently with `www.youtube.com/watch?v=.....` Some have patterns like `www.youtu.be/...` or `youtube.com/embed/...`.

Here's the parser I use, it worked every time for any Youtube URL so far :

```
videoId = url.match(/(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com\/(?:[^\/]+\/.+\/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)\/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be\/)([^"&?\/ ]{11})/i)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `id` always comes in the end.

```
function getId(url){
    var splitedValue = url.split("/");
    return splitedValue[splitedValue.length-1];
}

getId("https://www.youtube.com/embed/juIJGBxj-4w");
```

`Output: juIJGBxj-4w`